# How to find the size of an Array List in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to write a piece of code using ArrayList and some of its member functions.

These are the steps I have to take:

1. Insert data into ArrayList;
2. Update the array list either by insertion or by deletion;
3. Get the size of ArrayList  by using member function .length().

I have to execute Step 2 by using member function .clear()
I have tried to execute Step 3 as well, but in my attempt, the size of the ArrayList is displayed as 1, not 0.

Can you provide me with a piece of code that executes these three steps?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting what that element is?

Comment: Code talks much better than thousand words.

Comment: why don't you use .size()

Comment: don't you mean `size()` instead of `length()`? Also, please show us your sourcecode.

Comment: You seem to be a bit mixed up between an array and `ArrayList`. Edit your question to be clearer.

Comment: `ArrayList` has no method named `length()`.  Use [`size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size%28%29).

Comment: `ArrayList.size()` **can't** return 1 directly after a clear. You need to show us your code.

Comment: code will make things clear here

Answer (score 6):

Use `arrayListName.size()` for ArrayLists.

Have a look at
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `size()` method to find size of the `ArrayList`.But I strongly recommend you to use `isEmpty()` method to check whether list is empty or not (instead of `list.size()==0` checking).
[ArrayList#isEmpty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#isEmpty)

> Returns true if this list contains no elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ArrayList.size()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size%28%29) to determine how many elements the ArrayList contains.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
    Collection<String> c = new ArrayList<String>();
    c.add("Hello");
    if (c.size() != 1) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    c.clear();
    if (c.size() != 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .size() method..i thought that you can print the element in the array list when you thought that the all elements are cleared from the arraylist to make sure that if it is cleared.or the method .clear() just reset the elements in the arrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

int size=ArrayList.size();